# How to handle charmap' codec can't encode character error when reading MySQL file using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have a sql file made up of multiple query commands such as create tables, update tables that spans over multiple lines and I want to read run those queries in a separate MySQL database.

I have a custom function based on python that reads the lines of query commands and whenever it find an end to a sql query statement i.e';' it first run that command then continue reading the file until it finds the next ending of a sql query the repeat the process.

Issue is, when I run the script read and tries to run the different sql commands, some tables are created and updated in the new MySQL database but some don't. From the log I'm getting below error when I run the script in Airflow composer.

> 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0130' in position 192923: character maps to undefined

*Custom function*

```
def exec_sql_file(cursor, sql_file):
    print ("\n[INFO] Executing SQL script file: '%s'" % (sql_file))
    statement = ""

    with open(sql_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if re.match(r'--', line):  # ignore sql comment lines
                continue
            if not re.search(r';$', line):  # keep appending lines that don't end in ';'
                statement = statement + line
            else:  # when you get a line ending in ';' then exec statement and reset for next statement
                statement = statement + line
                #print "\n\n[DEBUG] Executing SQL statement:\n%s" % (statement)
                try:
                    cursor.execute(statement)
                except (my.OperationalError, my.ProgrammingError) as e:
                    print ("\n[WARN] MySQLError during execute statement \n\tArgs: '%s'" % (str(e.args)))

                statement = ""

# Run command
exec_sql_file(cursor=cursor, sql_file=file_path)
```

Here is a snippet of the sql file

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings` (
  `column_alias_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `code_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`column_alias_name`),
  KEY `FK_xx_code_id` (`code_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_xx_code_id` FOREIGN KEY (`code_id`) REFERENCES `m_code` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings`
--

LOCK TABLES `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `x_table_cloumn_code_mappings` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `x_table_column_code_mappings`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `x_table_column_code_mappings`;
```

I have tried to switch from encoding='utf8' to encoding='utf-8' but still same error. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Switch to binary mode (`open(..., 'rb')`). Even if the dump was utf encoded, it might contain  binary data. I'd also note that parsing SQL queries like this is extremely naive; the pattern might plausibly match some column data

Comment: Also SQL scripts can change the statement delimiter, for example this is necessary to define stored procedures, triggers, or events. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Show us the hex of the character(s) in question -- in the incoming file.